# Multiple assignments in one line

Tags: c#

I got a task to rewrite C# code in NodeJs. Unfortunately there are some nasty oneliners in that function which I do not fully understand.

**Code**

```
int b, sign = ((b = byteBuffer.ReadByte()) >> 6) & 1, i = b & 0x3F, offset = 6;
```

**Question**

I can see that there are multiple assignments, but I am not sure what values these variables are supposed to have.

Could someone explain this oneliner and/or rewrite it into a simpler to understand C# snippet?

Comment: "these two variables", since the line declares 4 variables, which two are you talking about in particular?

Comment: Oh then ignore this (gonna edit it). I thought these were just 2 variables, I simply didn't understand that it declares 4 variables

Comment: Also, assuming `byteBuffer` is a `Stream`, can't you simply copy and paste this line of code into your C# code?

Comment: As described I am rewriting it into NodeJS and I do not want to copy code that I do not understand, even if it works :(. I dislike such oneliners because they are hard to understand

Comment: Ah, sorry, *into* NodeJS, then forget that comment.

Comment: Not only are they hard to understand, the author has also seemingly made it even harder because he first declares the `b` variable, then assigns to it as part of the next variable declaration. It would make much more sense as `int b = byteBuffer.ReadByte(), sign = (b >> 6) & 1, i = b & 0x3f, offset = 6;`, that is, if we still want to keep it as a oneliner.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: maybe a poor attempt at code obfuscation? :) or copy-paste-refactor from something like `while(b=byteBuffer.ReadByte())`

Comment: Could be, it's probably more like the latter, I don't think that line was particularly obfuscated :)

Comment: I loathe the person that wrote that line of code. Absolute, seething hatred.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Agree, they should have defined `offset` first in the series so that it could be used in the binary shift when assigning `sign`. Also, it's a waste of characters and leads to finger cramps typing `sign` and `offset`. They should follow a consistent naming pattern and call those variables `s` and `o`, respectively.. `int b, o = 6, s = ((b = byteBuffer.ReadByte()) >> o) & 1, i = b & 0x3F`  :p

Comment: @RufusL Yeah, much clearer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's the same as

```
int b = byteBuffer.ReadByte();
int sign = (b >> 6) & 1;
int i = b & 0x3F;
int offset = 6;
```

In detail:

In the original line, each top-level `,` splits the declaration:

```
int b, sign = ((b = byteBuffer.ReadByte()) >> 6) & 1, i = b & 0x3F, offset = 6;
     ^here                                          ^here         ^ here
```

and then you're left with a tricky :

```
int b;
int sign = ((b = byteBuffer.ReadByte()) >> 6) & 1;
// ...
```

which in fact first defines B as without initial value, but then the next expression immediatelly assigns the result of 'ReadByte' to the B as the first sub-operation, so in fact it's the same as initializing B with it from the start, and you end up with what I wrote in the first code snippet.

Comment: Holy moly, I am glad there is Stack Overflow with such a great C# community. Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: You thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer.

Comment: @DourHighArch Not possible within 15 minutes ;)